# Knockout.js - Trying to add JSON to viewmodel is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I've seen several issues with this, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

What I'm trying to do is take a JSON object I get back from the server, which looks like this:

```
{
  "firstname": "Blanchard",
  "lastname": "Buckner",
  ...
}
```

The View Model does the AJAX call, and the data seems to be setup correctly. But when I try to pass it in to my singleContact function to bind to the view, nothing happens.

I'm new to Knockout, so I'm sure I'm making a pretty easy mistake, but I've tried for a while to figure it out and nothing is working.

```
// Binds json db data to each contact.
function singleContact(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.firstName = data.firstname;
  self.lastName = data.lastname;

  self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName;    
  }, self);

  self.image = data.image;
  self.position = data.position;
  self.company = data.company;
};

function detailViewModel(contactID) {
  var self = this;

  self.contactID = ko.observable(contactID);
  self.contact = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.getContact = function(id) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/contacts/' + id,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(singleContact(data)); <---- Always Undefined. The data is a JSON object.
      }
    });
  }

  self.getContact(self.contactID());
};
```

edit:
And here is the markup, should've included that the first time around.

```
<!-- ko foreach: contact -->
  <img class="contact__image" data-bind="attr:{src: image, alt: fullName}" />
  <h1 data-bind="text: fullName"></h1>
  <h2>
    <span data-bind="text: position"></span>,
    <span data-bind="text: company"></span>
  </h2>

  <h5>Notes on <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></h5>
  <p></p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Can you post your markup as well so I can see how your bindings are specified?

Comment: Andrew, It's been added. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `new` keyword to create a singleContact object:

```
var contact = new singleContact(data);
```

this can then be assigned to an observable on the detailViewModel:

```
self.singlecontact(contact);
```

I'd also recommend you use Upper Camelcase for the viewModel. ie. `DetailViewModel` instead of `detailViewModel` as you would in any other language when using object orientated programming.

Comment: @AndrewMount. The tutorial doesn't use this casing: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving. I couldn't find the docs with this casing also. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html. Objects should be camel case. Functions used to new objects should be Upper Camel case. I answered before the edit was made. The view wasn't there.

Comment: Fair enough, in their docs on observables their view model is camel case but I do see they mixed and use upper camel in the link provided.  I also did not realize you didn't see the markup.  I will remove my comment.

Comment: @AndrewMount please explain what you mean by mixed. View model functions are upper camel case and view models are camel case.

Comment: If you look here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html they use lower camel because they aren't actually constructing an instance.  I hastily glanced at it and put my foot where my mouth resides.

Comment: @AndrewMount in that docs they are only view models so they are camel case. If a function was used for the ViewModel type the function name would be upper camel case

Comment: I'm agreeing with you, a constructor function would be upper camel.  In the example I quickly glanced at (and linked), it was just an instance of a plain JS object, thus lower (and thus my foot in mouth comment), cheers.

Comment: Please don't get snarky.  I understand the differences quite clearly.  I was being hasty and typed faster than I thought.  Good night.

Comment: @AndrewMount I wasn't trying to be nasty. Just thought you didn't understand when to use what case

Comment: Understood.  it's late here and I'm cranky.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example. What is missing is that you were not pushing your created model into the observableArray.  I've shown that you can get back an array of results and push those in easily.

```js
function DetailViewModel(id) {
  var self = this;
  self.contacts = ko.observableArray([]);

  // make ajax call.. mocking here
  var results = ajax();

  results.forEach(function(result) {
    self.contacts.push(new Contact(result));
  });
}

function Contact(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.firstName = data.firstName;
  self.lastName = data.lastName;
  self.company = data.company;
  self.position = data.position;
  self.image = data.image;

  self.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName;
  });

  return self;
}

function ajax() {
  return [{
    firstName: 'Rich',
    lastName: 'Hickey',
    company: 'Cognitect',
    position: 'CTO',
    image: 'http://gotocon.com/dl/photos/speakers/Rich%20Hickey2.jpg'
  }, {
    firstName: 'Scott',
    lastName: 'Hanselman',
    company: 'Microsoft',
    position: 'Architect',
    image: 'http://www.globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/scott_hanselman.jpg'
  }];
}

$(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new DetailViewModel());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: contacts -->
<div>
  <img class="contact__image" data-bind="attr:{src: image, alt: fullName}" style="width: 100px; height: 150px" />
  <h1 data-bind="text: fullName"></h1>
  <h2>
    <span data-bind="text: position"></span>,
    <span data-bind="text: company"></span>
  </h2>

  <h5>Notes on <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></h5>

</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```